# Select data frame columns where column names are stored in a string

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a concatenated string having column names in it:

```
col_names = paste(c("Age", "Sex", "City", "Name"), collapse=', ')
col_names
[1] "Age, Sex, City, Name"
```

I also have a `data frame=df` that has 100s of variables. 
How can I select the columns present in my string (`col_names`) from the `df` using `col_names`?

Comment: `df[names(read.csv(text = col_names))]` would work.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `scan` to get the `vector` of names, remove the trailing/leading spaces with `trimws` and use that to subset the dataset.

```
df[trimws(scan(text=col_names, sep=",", what=''))]
```

Or another option is `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
df[str_extract_all(col_names, '\\w+')[[1]]]
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(Age= c(5, 3, 25), Sex = c("M", "F", 
 "M"), Value = 1:3, City= c("Brookings",
 "Mumbai", "Paris"), Name = LETTERS[1:3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Does using the strsplit function help? It will split your string into a character vector by some sort of separator. Here I use the function to subset a data frame (courtesy of akrun) by the variables in the string.

```
df <- data.frame(Age= c(5, 3, 25), Sex = c("M", "F", 
 "M"), Value = 1:3, City= c("Brookings",
 "Mumbai", "Paris"), Name = LETTERS[1:3])

df[,strsplit(col_names, ", ")[[1]]]

   Age Sex      City Name
1   5   M Brookings    A
2   3   F    Mumbai    B
3  25   M     Paris    C
```

Answer (score 0):

##### The simple answer

If you have dataframe `df` and column name `"Column_Name"`, you can access the column as a vector like this:

```
df[["Column_Name"]]
```

So, when you use the `colnames(df)` function, you can use the strings returned to access the columns you need.  A very similar method works for multiple columns:

```
df[c("Column_1", "Column_2", "Column_3")]
```

Notice that using only one set of square brackets (`[]`) will return a sub-dataframe, while using two sets (`[[]]`) will return a vector.

In your situation, you may want to consider leaving out the `paste()` function.  The following will work just fine:

```
col_names = c("Age", "Sex", "City", "Name")
col_data = df[col_names]
```